# Future declaration seems independent from promise

Tags: scala, promise, future

I was reading this article http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/16/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-9-promises-and-futures-in-practice.html and I was looking at this code:

```
object Government {
  def redeemCampaignPledge(): Future[TaxCut] = {
    val p = Promise[TaxCut]()
    Future {
      println("Starting the new legislative period.")
      Thread.sleep(2000)
      p.success(TaxCut(20))
      println("We reduced the taxes! You must reelect us!!!!1111")
    }
    p.future
  }
}
```

I've seen this type of code a few times and I'm confused. So we have this `Promise`:

```
val p = Promise[TaxCut]()
```

And this `Future`:

```
Future {
  println("Starting the new legislative period.")
  Thread.sleep(2000)
  p.success(TaxCut(20))
  println("We reduced the taxes! You must reelect us!!!!1111")
}
```

I don't see any assignment between them so I don't understand: How are they connected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't see any assignment between them so I don't understand: How are
>   they connected?

A `Promise` is a one way of creating a `Future`.

When you use `Future { }` and import `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`, you're queuing a function on one of Scala's threadpool threads. But, that isn't the only way to generate a `Future`. A `Future` need not necessarily be scheduled on a different thread.

What this example does is:

1. Creates a `Promise[TaxCut]` which will be completed sometime in the near future.
2. Queues a function to be ran inside a threadpool thread via the `Future` apply. This function also completes the `Promise` via the [`Promise.success`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Promise@success(value:T):Promise.this.type) method
3. Returns the future generated by the promise via [`Promise.future`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Promise@future:scala.concurrent.Future[T]). When this future returns, it may not be completed yet, depending on how fast the execution of the function queued to the `Future` really runs (the OP was trying to convey this via the `Thread.sleep` method, delaying the completion of the future).

Comment: `Future { }` is not a macro. It is just apply method in companion object.

Comment: @Łukasz Thanks for that, was under the impression it was a macro for some reason.